# Post request fails because of entity saying that The instance of entity type 'WorkEntry' cannot be tracked because

Tags: c#, entity-framework, post, entity

I'm using an InMemory DB from entity with which I keep having problems. having the controller below, I keep getting an error like this `The instance of entity type 'WorkEntry' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.` when doing a post on the id/workEntry route.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProjectsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApiContext _context;

    public ProjectsController(ApiContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{Id:int}")]
    public string HelloWorld(int id)
    {
        return "Hello Back!";
    }


    // GET api/projects
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() //async
    {
        return Ok(_context.Projects.Include(x => x.WorkEntries));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Project prj)
    {
        try
        {
            if (prj != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Post--->  " + prj.Id + " " + prj.Name + " " + prj.StartDate + " " + prj.EndDate );
                _context.Projects.Add(prj);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Ok("Added new project with ID=" +prj.Id);
            }
            return BadRequest("Project is null");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }

    //[HttpPut("{id}")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{Id:int}/WorkEntry")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync(int id, WorkEntry workEntry)
    {
        try
        {
            if (workEntry != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("asta e WorkEntryyyyy---- " + workEntry);
                var updatedProject = _context.Projects.Include(x => x.WorkEntries).First(x => x.Id == id);
                Console.WriteLine(updatedProject.ToString());

                updatedProject.WorkEntries.Add(workEntry);
                _context.Projects.Attach(updatedProject);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                //db.Books.AddOrUpdate(book)
                return Ok("project with ID=" + updatedProject.Id + " was updated");

            }
            return BadRequest("Project or WorkEntities is null");///schimba

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I tried different approaches in where I was using AsNoTracking or using update but nothing got me anywhere.
Any hint is good for me:)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `_context.Projects.Attach(updatedProject);` because by default `EntityFramework` track records when read from database and when you attach an entity to `EntityFramework` that tracked by `Wntitifeamrwork` this error occurred

> The instance of entity type 'WorkEntry' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'id'} is already being tracked

You should remove
`_context.Projects.Attach(updatedProject);` or use `.AsNoTracking()` to fix this error.

1. Remove `.Attach(updatedProject);`

```cs
var updatedProject = _context.Projects.Include(x => x.WorkEntries).First(x => x.Id == id);
Console.WriteLine(updatedProject.ToString());
updatedProject.WorkEntries.Add(workEntry);
//_context.Projects.Attach(updatedProject);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

2. using `.AsNoTracking()`

```cs
var updatedProject = _context.Projects.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.WorkEntries).First(x => x.Id == id);
Console.WriteLine(updatedProject.ToString());
updatedProject.WorkEntries.Add(workEntry);
_context.Projects.Attach(updatedProject);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: What you told me here helped me a lot, but the thing is that my db doesn't save any changes whatsoever. everything else is working now but nothing gets saved.

Comment: is there need a _context.Projects.Update(updatedProject); maybe? but if i use that then i go back at having this error System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'WorkEntry' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given
key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Comment: @40love Are you use one of my solutions? you shouldn't use both of solutions. you can use one of them

Answer (score 0):

Farhad's answer should cover the most likely issues. One other thing to check is that it looks like you're using Dependency Injection so ensure that your DbContext is set up with a lifetime scope of Per Request and not something like Singleton.

The other thing is that it's not clear if you are attempting to Add a WorkEntry or Update one. The code you have (minus the `Attach`) should work for an Add scenario. If you want to Update, then you should copy across the values from your passed in model into the loaded & tracked entity. Automapper is handy for assistihg here:

```
var updatedProject = _context.Projects.Include(x => x.WorkEntries).Single(x => x.Id == id);

var existingWorkEntry = updatedProject.WorkEntries.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == workEntry.Id);
if (existingWorkEntry != null)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<WorkEntry, WorkEntry>());
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    mapper.Map(existingWorkEntry, workEntry);
}
else // Include this if the method could receive a new Work Entry...
    updatedProject.WorkEntries.Add(workEntry);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Be sure to validate any/all data coming from the client in a POST call very thoroughly as it could be tampered with using debug tools and the like. Passing entities between client and server and attaching them to set modified state is vulnerable to tampering, and very inefficient in terms of memory use  & transfer payload size.  This same technique with Automapper can be applied to updating entities using more streamlined ViewModel/DTO objects, reducing the data sent across the wire to just what the view needs to relay rather than entire entities.